# Button not consistently recognizing tapped event

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a couple of buttons on a canvas.
One button consistently recognizes tapped events while the other does not.

If I enlarge the button to a gross size and then tap it, then the "Tapped" event is captured.

The code is below:

```
        <Canvas>
            <Image Source="Assets/us_map_portrait.png" />
            <Button Canvas.Left="320" Canvas.Top="214" Tapped="Button_Tapped" Tag="FL">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Ellipse Height="50" Width="25" Fill="Transparent" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
                            <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                                <CompositeTransform Rotation="-29.541"/>
                            </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                        </Ellipse>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>

            <Button Canvas.Left="292" Canvas.Top="86" Tapped="Button_Tapped" Tag="OH" >
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Ellipse  Height="35" Width="35" Fill="Red" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
                            <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                                <CompositeTransform Rotation="-14.684"/>
                            </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                        </Ellipse>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>

        </Canvas>
```

Comment: They are overlapping, right? So the smaller button never raises Tapped event or only rarely?

Comment: No. The buttons do not overlap. They do sit on top of a canvas though.

Comment: While troubleshooting, I realized that if I move the button further down the canvas, then the tapped event works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the canvas contained within a list view.
When I removed the list view, the issue got resolved.

Translated, the list view may have been swallowing the event.